# Getting an AlertDialogFragment's message and title to change based on different errors

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am trying to get an alertDialog popup to change it's text depending on what error occurred. There are two errors i am looking for, one is no network found/connected, another is the data received from an HTTP request is bad/wrong/incorrect. 
First, I thought that using a Constructor in my DialogFragment class would work, and send the class/object an 'errorcode', and have the constructor change String variables, and have those String variables be .setTitle, .setMessage, etc. However, you apparently cannot use contructors with fragments! You need to use bundles of arguments or something strange that I do not understand. I tried to get it to work, but whenever one of the two errors occur, the screen darkens like a dialog is there, but no dialog actually shows at all.

Here is my Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
//public static final MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String apiKey = "3b2a6c9aed11e80da43168ee303b588c";
    double latitude = 454534523; //37.8267;
    double longitude = -122.423;
    String forecastURL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey +
            "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        //begin using OkHttp library recipe for Synchronous Get
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(forecastURL)   //.url(requestBinURL)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    Log.v(TAG, response.body().string());
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    } else { // This is an HTTP error, bad data was sent or received.
                            // sending error code 1
                        alertUserAboutError(1);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
        else { // attempting to make existing Toast message into an Alert Dialog Message
             //Toast.makeText(this, "Network is unavailable!",
               //     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // This works, but is very messy and completely blurs the lines between the AlertDialogFragment class and this activity.
        // sending error code 2
        alertUserAboutError(2);
        }

    Log.d(TAG, "Main UI code is running");
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isAvailable = true;
    }
    return isAvailable;
}

private void alertUserAboutError(int errorCode) {
    if (errorCode == 1) {
        //AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(1);

        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    } else if (errorCode == 2) {
       // AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(2);
        /*dialog.builder.setTitle("There was a network error!")
                .setMessage("Network was not found!")
                .setPositiveButton("Dismiss", null);*/
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }
}
```

}

Here is my AlertDialogFragment class:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
// public  Context context = getActivity();
// public AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

String alertTitle;
String alertMessage;
String alertButtonMessage;


public static final AlertDialogFragment newInstance(int errorCode){
    AlertDialogFragment fragment = new AlertDialogFragment();

    final Bundle intArg = new Bundle(1);
    intArg.putInt("INT_ERROR_CODE",errorCode);
    fragment.setArguments(intArg);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context context = getActivity();
    int errorCode = getArguments().getInt("INT_ERORR_CODE");
    //errorState of 1 is for HTTP CallBack error
    //errorState of 2 is for unavailable network error

    if (errorCode == 1){
        alertTitle = context.getString(R.string.alert_title_http);
        alertMessage = context.getString(R.string.alert_message_http);
        alertButtonMessage = context.getString(R.string.alert_button_http);
    } else if (errorCode == 2) {
        alertTitle = context.getString(R.string.alert_title_network);
        alertMessage = context.getString(R.string.alert_message_network) +
                context.getString(R.string.alert_title_message2);
        alertButtonMessage = context.getString(R.string.alert_button_network);
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle((alertTitle))  //(alertTitle)
            .setMessage((alertMessage)) // (alertMessage)
            .setPositiveButton((alertButtonMessage), null); // (alertButtonMessage)
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
```

}

Please note that I did leave out all of my import statements. If they are relevant, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The preblem arise cause creating both `DialogFragment` and `AlertDialog` both.

No need to create `DialogFragment` if have you  `AlertDialog`

put your dialog code in activity like this

```
private void alertUserAboutError(int errorCode) {
    if (errorCode == 1){
        alertTitle = context.getString(R.string.alert_title_http);
        alertMessage = context.getString(R.string.alert_message_http);
        alertButtonMessage = context.getString(R.string.alert_button_http);
    } else if (errorCode == 2) {
        alertTitle = context.getString(R.string.alert_title_network);
        alertMessage = context.getString(R.string.alert_message_network) +
                context.getString(R.string.alert_title_message2);
        alertButtonMessage = context.getString(R.string.alert_button_network);
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle((alertTitle))  //(alertTitle)
            .setMessage((alertMessage)) // (alertMessage)
            .setPositiveButton((alertButtonMessage), null); // (alertButtonMessage)
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. So your suggestion is to just forget about creating the separate AlertDialogFragment class? And put the code for creating and showing the AlertDialog directly into the Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Use this just pass the error message according to your response code

```
/**
     * Creates an alert dialog
     * @param iContext current context`
     */
    public static AlertDialog.Builder showAlertDialog(Context iContext,String errorMessage) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(iContext).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(errorMessage);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.show(); // Show the alert dialog.
        return alertDialog;
    }
```

Check your response and pass the message accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I'm sort of confused here. Would this be used in the AlertDialog class as a sort of constructor? Call the showAlertDialog static class, passing in the error message from my Activity class?

Comment: Just place this method in a class and call it like Demo.showAlertDialog(this,message). Please accept this answer if this works...thanks